# parsing the Json value from server side in android

Tags: json, android-json

I am getting the response from server side and also long days this code is worked but now this code rise the exception.

```
  (org.json.JSONException: Value null at product of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray)
```

{"success":true,"customer":[{"id":26,"customer":"user1","product":[{"product":"Inspection"},{"product":"Exhaust Fan"},{"product":"fixing cum Termination"},{"product":"fixing cum Termination"}],"job_description":"","customer_rewards":""},{"id":25,"customer":"‌user2","product":[{"product":"Water Purifier"}],"job_description":"","customer_rewards":""}]}

```
 ** code **
       boolean status=jsonObject.getBoolean("success");
            if (status) {
                JSONArray jobarray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("customer");
                if (jobarray.length()!=0) {
                    for (int i=0;i<jobarray.length();i++) {
                        AllJobsobject allJobsObject=new AllJobsobject();
                        JSONObject jobobject=jobarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        allJobsObject.setId(jobobject.getInt("id"));
                      allJobsObject.setJob_name(jobobject.getString("customer"));

                            JSONArray productArray = jobobject.getJSONArray("product");
                            ArrayList<Products> productsList = new ArrayList<Products>();
                        for (int n = 0; n < productArray.length(); n++) {
                            JSONObject productObject = productArray.getJSONObject(n);
                            Products product = new Products();
                            product.setName(productObject.getString("product"));
                            productsList.add(product);
                          }
                          allJobsObject.setProductsList(productsList);

                     datas.add(allJobsObject);
                   }
                }
```

Comment: JSONArray productArray = jobobject.getJSONArray("product"); this line that exception is rising.

Comment: Can you please post a valid json

Comment: This is the response  {"success": true
"customer": [0]
0:{
"id": 26
"product": [4]
0:{"product": "test0"}
-1:{"product": "test1"}
-2:{"product": "test2}
-3:{"product": "test3"}
"job_description": "product description"
]}

Comment: This is not a valid json, that's why you face some difficulties while reading it. You can check using http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Ok but last 4 months i am working this code and getting this response only, its worked fine and no problem suddenly this exception is showing. sorry i am putting the full response in that online json validator. its showing correct response no error and exception.

Comment: If you can compare this response with you got before 4 months, you probably will see difference.

Comment: {"success":true,"customer_jobs":[{"id":26,"customer":"kishore kishore","product":[{"product":"Inspection"},{"product":"Ceiling or Exhaust Fan"},{"product":"ELCB fixing cum Termination"},{"product":"RCCB fixing cum Termination"}],"job_description":"","customer_rewards":""},{"id":25,"customer":"kishore kishore","product":[{"product":"RO Water Purifier"}],"job_description":"","customer_rewards":""}]}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103924/discussion-between-fuat-coskun-and-saravanan-selvam).

Answer (score 1):

```
org.json.JSONException: Value null at product of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Exception says that your field "product" is null instead of a json array. Your example json seems valid and "product" field is an array as expected. Probably sometimes the response you are trying to read contains null "product" field as below :

```
{
..
"product" : null
..
}
```

You should do null check on jobobject.

```
jobobject.isNull("product")
```